# Shifting the Contents of a char Array One Spot to the Left

Tags: c

I have a lab for my course Software Development and really new in C - but I know Java better. I am trying to shift the contents of the array one spot to the left but the output seems to be same with the user input. Spotting any problems?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char telephoneNumber[13];
    int i;

    printf("Enter a telephone number [(xxx)xxx-xxxx]: ");
    scanf("%c", &telephoneNumber);

    for (i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        telephoneNumber[i] = telephoneNumber[i + 1];
    }

    printf("%c", telephoneNumber);
    return 0;
}
```

Input: `(902)494-9999`

Output: `(902)494-9999`

Comment: Is it me, or are your inputs and outputs the same? I guess that's what you're actually outputting. Could you show the inputs and outputs you expect?

Comment: 1) `scanf("%c", &telephoneNumber);` --> `scanf("%13c", telephoneNumber);` 2) `for (i = 0; i < 11; i++)` --> `for (i = 0; i < 12; i++)` 3) `printf("%c", telephoneNumber);` --> `printf("%.12s", telephoneNumber);`

Comment: Both `%c` and `%s` (which you should be using but are not) require the same target type, a `char*`, You actually passing `char(*)[13]`, which in your case resolves to the same address (lucky you), but the types don't match and any decent C compiler with proper warnings enabled would tell you that. Further, I see no way short of random-miracle that output could come from the posted code. The only thing mostly *right* in this code is the actual shifting for-loop, oddly the subject of your question. Is the *real* problem you're trying to solve to take an input, then strip everything but digits?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY `scanf("%13c"` => `scanf("%12c"` since buffer is of 13 length (that was in my correct & downvoted answer that I just deleted)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre There is no problem if you do not use null-terminator. By the way, I have not downvoted your answer.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY. I was assuming that the OP wanted to use `printf("%s",`. thanks for your reply. I feel that this deleted answer gets me as much points as if it hadn't been downvoted, since it wouldn't have been upvoted either :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Perhaps the reason for the downvote is that you do not mention the expansion of the size and _scanf("%c", &telephoneNumber);
is correct_.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I don't get that downvote either. What you pointed out was obviously correct (at a minimum, far more correct than what the OP had coming in). Someone woke up on the wrong side of the bed, I guess.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: I see: that's _not_ correct! Since the answer was providing the solution, I'd just have left a comment about that instead of downvoting. Probably a mix of "answering noob question + answering bulls**t on the side". Never mind. Got my upvotes on better questions today. Thanks goes to you both. I always learn from my mistakes.

Comment: For the OP, what you want to do with the first and last digit? do you want the last digit to become the first? or just overwrite it?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: `scanf("%13c"` will not overflow the destination array, but there is no way to tell how many bytes were stored if the line does not end with a newline and there is no null terminator.  It would be much better to use `scanf("%12s"` to get a proper C string.

Comment: @chqrlie if you use `%13s`, first change `char telephoneNumber[13];` to `char telephoneNumber[14];`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: Of course! My earlier comment was premature. Yet I do not understand how you can make sense of the input received by `scanf("%13c"`

Comment: Also `scanf("%12s"`  can not store the expected input.

Comment: @chqrlie That is because the input format is defined as **(xxx)xxx-xxxx**, but of course CString is common as a string.

Comment: Correct! the array needs to be at least 14 bytes long. You must check the return value of `scanf()`. `%13c` will read exactly 13 bytes or fail, whereas `%13s` will skip whitespace and read at least 1 byte and at most 13 bytes (non whitespace).

Comment: Dare to say, the leading whitespace character is invalid format. And it is checkable.  Perhaps the return value need not be checked except for EOF.

Answer (score 1):

I made a few slight changes to your program, and it works for me as expected.
I'm not sure why it didn't work for you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char telephoneNumber[20];
    int i;
    int len;

    printf("Enter a telephone number [(xxx)xxx-xxxx]: ");
    scanf("%19s", telephoneNumber);

    len = strlen(telephoneNumber);
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        telephoneNumber[i] = telephoneNumber[i + 1];
    }

    printf("%s\n", telephoneNumber);
    return 0;
}
```

I made two changes:

- I changed your `printf` and `scanf` formats to `%s`
- I change your shift-to-the-left loop to operate on the actual length of the string (which I increased to a max of 20, just in case)

There's one subtlety you might not be aware of: strings in C are terminated by a (usually invisible) nul character, represented as `'\0'`, and it's important to shift that character to the left along with the rest of the string.  (But your code *does* shift it, whether you realized it or not, so that's not the problem.)

Comment: The number passed to scanf in the conversion specifier is the maximum number of characters to store into the destination before the null terminator, so t should be 19: `scanf("%19s", telephoneNumber);`

Comment: @chqrlie Yikes, right, thanks.  Fixed.  (`scanf` sucks.  Can you tell I never use it?)